# Installing released Office Add- In returns error

Tags: vb.net, github, powerpoint, add-in, release

I build a PowerPoint Add- In with Visual Studio 2015 and published it to github. With setup.exe and everything. The Problem is that neither the setup nor the vsto itself seems to work.

When I install the local version no errors occur, but when I download it from github and try to install I get several errors:

- Something referencing Security Zones
- Installer is unable to download vsto

The Url is set correctly. I'm using the visual studio built in publishing tools --> ClickOnce.

### Pictures

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I think it has to do with the clickOnce. Are there any alternatives or do you have some experienve with it

Answer (score 1):

There is another alternative to develop the .exe file. It is using InstallShield. 
Here is the link which will guide you to it. Please follow the procedure shown in the MSDN. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396